# amChart draggable pie chart rendering dummy slide

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am attempting to add a chart from amChart into my php project and everything seems to be going OK, I have two parameters and when I change them, it loads the data into my array.

I am using a new chat, [a draggable pie chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/dragging-pie-slices/#code) and this chart seems to be making use of a "dummy" slide to do percentages and calculations.

The problem is, when my data first loads, it loads this dummy slide which of course throws off my dat and I have to manually drag it out for my chart to be correct.

[image: Chart Results]
I have inserted my code below, alot of the code is from the libary and my changes only involve the ajax code used to manipulate the data of the chart.

Grateful for any assistance.

```
<script>

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end
var data;

     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//       appHandleUniform()   
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            rtl: App.isRTL(),
            autoclose: true,
            weekStart: app_cfg_first_day_of_week,
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            clearBtn: true,
        });


    });

 var pData;
    var data  = [{
    "country": "Dummy",
    "disabled": true,
    "litres": 1000,
    "color": am4core.color("#dadada"),
    "opacity": 0.3,
    "strokeDasharray": "4,4"
} /*{
    "country": "Apple",
    "litres": 501.9
}, {
    "country": "Pest",
    "litres": 301.9
}, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
}, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
}, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
}, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
}*/ ];

// cointainer to hold both charts
var container = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4core.Container);
container.width = am4core.percent(100);
container.height = am4core.percent(100);
container.layout = "horizontal";

container.events.on("maxsizechanged", function () {
    chart1.zIndex = 0;
    separatorLine.zIndex = 1;
    dragText.zIndex = 2;
    chart2.zIndex = 3;
})

var chart1 = container.createChild(am4charts.PieChart);
 chart1.validateData();
    var startDate = endDate = "";
    $("#start_date").change(function () {
        startDate = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#end_date").change(function () {
        endDate = $(this).val();
        if (startDate != "" && endDate != "") {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo url_for("charts/getEntryFormsData") ?>',
                data: {startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate},
                success: function (data) {

                      pData = $.parseJSON(data);    

// or
//chart1.validateData();    
  chart1.data  = [{
    "country": "Dummy",
    "disabled": true,
    "litres": 1000,
    "color": am4core.color("#dadada"),
    "opacity": 0.3,
    "strokeDasharray": "4,4"
},{
    "country": "CTR",
    "litres": pData["CTR"].length
}, {
    "country": "DRFI",
    "litres": pData["DRFI"].length
}, {
    "country": "FIUIN",
    "litres": pData["FIUIN"].length
}, {
    "country": "RFA",
    "litres": pData["RFA"].length
}, {
    "country": "RFIR",
    "litres": pData["RFIR"].length
}, {
    "country": "TPR",
    "litres": pData["TPR"].length
}];



                                     }
                             });

        } else {
            alert("Choose Start Date First");
            $("#end_date").val("");
       }
    });

         //  chart1.data=data;      
chart1 .fontSize = 11;
chart1.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this makes initial fade in effect
//chart1.data = data;
//chart1.validateData();

chart1.radius = am4core.percent(70);
chart1.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);
chart1.zIndex = 1;



var series1 = chart1.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
series1.dataFields.value = "litres";
series1.dataFields.category = "country";
series1.colors.step = 2;
series1.alignLabels = false;
series1.labels.template.bent = true;
series1.labels.template.radius = 3;
series1.labels.template.padding(0,0,0,0);

var sliceTemplate1 = series1.slices.template;
sliceTemplate1.cornerRadius = 5;
sliceTemplate1.draggable = true;
sliceTemplate1.inert = true;
sliceTemplate1.propertyFields.fill = "color";
sliceTemplate1.propertyFields.fillOpacity = "opacity";
sliceTemplate1.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
sliceTemplate1.propertyFields.strokeDasharray = "strokeDasharray";
sliceTemplate1.strokeWidth = 1;
sliceTemplate1.strokeOpacity = 1;

var zIndex = 5;

sliceTemplate1.events.on("down", function (event) {
    event.target.toFront();
    // also put chart to front
    var series = event.target.dataItem.component;
    series.chart.zIndex = zIndex++;
})

series1.ticks.template.disabled = true;

sliceTemplate1.states.getKey("active").properties.shiftRadius = 0;

sliceTemplate1.events.on("dragstop", function (event) {
    handleDragStop(event);
})

// separator line and text
var separatorLine = container.createChild(am4core.Line);
separatorLine.x1 = 0;
separatorLine.y2 = 300;
separatorLine.strokeWidth = 3;
separatorLine.stroke = am4core.color("#dadada");
separatorLine.valign = "middle";
separatorLine.strokeDasharray = "5,5";


var dragText = container.createChild(am4core.Label);
dragText.text = "Drag slices over the line";
dragText.rotation = 90;
dragText.valign = "middle";
dragText.align = "center";
dragText.paddingBottom = 5;

// second chart
var chart2 = container.createChild(am4charts.PieChart);
chart2.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this makes initial fade in effect
chart2 .fontSize = 11;
chart2.radius = am4core.percent(70);


// or
//chart1.validateData();    
  chart2.data  = [{
    "country": "Dummy",
    "disabled": true,
    "litres": 1000,
    "color": am4core.color("#dadada"),
    "opacity": 0.3,
    "strokeDasharray": "4,4"
}, {
    "country": "CTR",
    "litres": 4
}, {
    "country": "DRFI",
    "litres":2
}, {
    "country": "FIUIN",
    "litres": 5
}, {
    "country": "RFA",
    "litres": 5
}, {
    "country": "RFIR",
    "litres":6
}, {
    "country": "TPR",
    "litres": 6
}];




chart2.validateData();
//chart2.data = data;
chart2.innerRadius = am4core.percent(40);
chart2.zIndex = 1;

var series2 = chart2.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
series2.dataFields.value = "litres";
series2.dataFields.category = "country";
series2.colors.step = 2;

series2.alignLabels = false;
series2.labels.template.bent = true;
series2.labels.template.radius = 3;
series2.labels.template.padding(0,0,0,0);
series2.labels.template.propertyFields.disabled = "disabled";

var sliceTemplate2 = series2.slices.template;
sliceTemplate2.copyFrom(sliceTemplate1);

series2.ticks.template.disabled = true;

function handleDragStop(event) {
    var targetSlice = event.target;
    var dataItem1;
    var dataItem2;
    var slice1;
    var slice2;

    if (series1.slices.indexOf(targetSlice) != -1) {
        slice1 = targetSlice;
        slice2 = series2.dataItems.getIndex(targetSlice.dataItem.index).slice;
    }
    else if (series2.slices.indexOf(targetSlice) != -1) {
        slice1 = series1.dataItems.getIndex(targetSlice.dataItem.index).slice;
        slice2 = targetSlice;
    }


    dataItem1 = slice1.dataItem;
    dataItem2 = slice2.dataItem;

    var series1Center = am4core.utils.spritePointToSvg({ x: 0, y: 0 }, series1.slicesContainer);
    var series2Center = am4core.utils.spritePointToSvg({ x: 0, y: 0 }, series2.slicesContainer);

    var series1CenterConverted = am4core.utils.svgPointToSprite(series1Center, series2.slicesContainer);
    var series2CenterConverted = am4core.utils.svgPointToSprite(series2Center, series1.slicesContainer);

    // tooltipY and tooltipY are in the middle of the slice, so we use them to avoid extra calculations
    var targetSlicePoint = am4core.utils.spritePointToSvg({ x: targetSlice.tooltipX, y: targetSlice.tooltipY }, targetSlice);

    if (targetSlice == slice1) {
        if (targetSlicePoint.x > container.pixelWidth / 2) {
            var value = dataItem1.value;

            dataItem1.hide();

            var animation = slice1.animate([{ property: "x", to: series2CenterConverted.x }, { property: "y", to: series2CenterConverted.y }], 400);
            animation.events.on("animationprogress", function (event) {
                slice1.hideTooltip();
            })

            slice2.x = 0;
            slice2.y = 0;

            dataItem2.show();
        }
        else {
            slice1.animate([{ property: "x", to: 0 }, { property: "y", to: 0 }], 400);
        }
    }
    if (targetSlice == slice2) {
        if (targetSlicePoint.x < container.pixelWidth / 2) {

            var value = dataItem2.value;

            dataItem2.hide();

            var animation = slice2.animate([{ property: "x", to: series1CenterConverted.x }, { property: "y", to: series1CenterConverted.y }], 400);
            animation.events.on("animationprogress", function (event) {
                slice2.hideTooltip();
            })

            slice1.x = 0;
            slice1.y = 0;
            dataItem1.show();
        }
        else {
            slice2.animate([{ property: "x", to: 0 }, { property: "y", to: 0 }], 400);
        }
    }

    toggleDummySlice(series1);
    toggleDummySlice(series2);

    series1.hideTooltip();
    series2.hideTooltip();
}

function toggleDummySlice(series) {
    var show = true;
    for (var i = 1; i < series.dataItems.length; i++) {
        var dataItem = series.dataItems.getIndex(i);
        if (dataItem.slice.visible && !dataItem.slice.isHiding) {
            show = false;
        }
    }

    var dummySlice = series.dataItems.getIndex(0);
    if (show) {
        dummySlice.show();
    }
    else {
        dummySlice.hide();
    }
}

series2.events.on("datavalidated", function () {

    var dummyDataItem = series2.dataItems.getIndex(0);
    dummyDataItem.show(0);
    dummyDataItem.slice.draggable = false;
    dummyDataItem.slice.tooltipText = undefined;

    for (var i = 1; i < series2.dataItems.length; i++) {
        series2.dataItems.getIndex(i).hide(0);
    }
})

series1.events.on("datavalidated", function () {
    var dummyDataItem = series1.dataItems.getIndex(0);
    dummyDataItem.hide(0);
    dummyDataItem.slice.draggable = false;
    dummyDataItem.slice.tooltipText = undefined;
})
</script>
```